# Allocating space from boot drive to another drive without rebooting?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition

I am running an Ubuntu 20 machine with two physically separate drives. The first one is my boot drive (`/dev/nvme0nlp3`) and the second one (`/dev/nvme0nlp1`) is where I run my application. My application needs more space and I want to allocate more from my boot drive to my application drive. How can I accomplish this without having to reboot my server?

Comment: how should this work? its not a peace of cake that can be cut in twice and put on the other side again?! Create a folder and use the space.

Comment: Thanks for your super unhelpful answer. It should work the following way: my application runs inside a directory on disk 2. I am running out of space on disk 2 and I want to make it possible for disk 2 to use disk 1's space. I am sure it is possible with LVM but not sure how can I do it without losing data on disk 2.

Comment: make a backup and create a lvm